# signed result of Val function in VBA

Tags: vba

I use vba in ms access,and found that ,if my parameter greater than 0x8000
less than 0x10000, the result is minus number

eg.   Val("&H8000") = -32768   Val("&HFFFF")= -1

how can i get the unsigned number?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem right here:

> ```
> ?TypeName(&HFFFF)
> Integer
> ```

The `Integer` type is 16-bit, and 65,535 overflows it. This is probably overkill, but it was fun to write:

```
Function ConvertHex(ByVal value As String) As Double
    
    If Left(value, 2) = "&H" Then
        value = Right(value, Len(value) - 2)
    End If
    
    Dim result As Double
    
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = Len(value) To 1 Step -1
        
        Dim digit As String
        digit = Mid$(value, i, 1)
        
        result = result + (16 ^ j) * Val("&H" & digit)
        j = j + 1
        
    Next
    
    ConvertHex = result
    
End Function
```

This function iterates each digit starting from the right, computing its value and adding it to the result as it moves to the leftmost digit.

---

```
?ConvertHex("&H10")
 16 
?ConvertHex("&HFF")
 255 
?ConvertHex("&HFFFF")
 65535 
?ConvertHex("&HFFFFFFFFFFFFF")
 281474976710655
```

---

#### UPDATE

As I suspected, there's a much better way to do this. [Credits to @Jonbot for this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105896/23788):

```
Function ConvertHex(ByVal value As String) As Currency
    Dim result As Currency
    result = CCur(value)

    If result < 0 Then
        'Add two times Int32.MaxValue and another 2 for the overflow
        'Because the hex value is apparently parsed as a signed Int64/Int32
        result = result + &H7FFFFFFF + &H7FFFFFFF + 2
    End If

    ConvertHex = result
End Function
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't really like this approach - [so I put it up for peer review on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/105873/23788).

Comment: @thed this answer is horrible - see the other one involving conversion functions.

Answer (score 2):

Append an ampersand to the hex literal to force conversion to a 32bit integer:

```
Val("&HFFFF" & "&") == 65535
Val("&H8000&")      == +32768
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Val`. Use one of the built-in conversion functions instead:

```
?CCur("&HFFFF")
 65535

?CDbl("&HFFFF")
 65535
```

Prefer `Currency` over `Double` in this case, to avoid floating-point issues.